# Non-abelian group cohomology, additional information

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, nonabelian-cohomology

Let $G$ be a (profinite) group, and let $M$ be a non-abelian $G$-module.
We know how to construct reasonably $H^0(G,M)$ and $H^1(G,M)$ and it turns out that $H^1(G,M)$ is just a pointed set and not group (we can also construct $H^2(G,M)$ but I don't sure how reasonable this construction actually is, and I don't know what about $H^i(G,M)$ where $i>2$).

Suppose we know how to define $H^i(G,M)$ properly, what is the additional information we get?

Comment: More terms in the "increasingly longer" exact sequence, presumably!  (It's probably hard to answer since I think we *haven't* defined many of the higher non-Abelian cohomology groups.)

Comment: $H^0(G,M)$ is a group!

Comment: Concerning $H^2$, see:  Springer, T. A. Nonabelian $H^2$ in Galois cohomology. 1966 Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder, Colo., 1965) pp. 164–182 Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I.

Comment: See also: Borovoi, Mikhail V. 
Abelianization of the second nonabelian Galois cohomology.
Duke Math. J. 72 (1993), no. 1, 217–239.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thank you!